# Comparative database metrics for different implementations of Django Model

Tags: django

Considering two approaches in designing Django models:

1 - Very few models, but each model has a long list of fields.

2 - Many models, each model has significantly shorter list of fields. But the models employ multi-level hierarchical one-to-many structure.

Suppose they both use Postgres as the database. In general, what would be the comparative database size, latency in retrieving, processing and updating data for these two approaches?

Comment: People often focus too much on performance, whereas typically the difference in performance is not that much. You should make a table for each entity and add relations between these entities. By making it 1 or 2, you typically will have bad modeling, which will require complex and inefficient queries, and a lot of work to implement features.

Comment: Ensure you use `select_related`/`prefetch_related` etc to query for necessary related objects in order to optimise performance and just have your models contain what is required.

Comment: This shall be answered based on DBMS you are using as each engine has a different strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: define models based on the *business logic*.

People often aim to optimize too early in the development process. As *Donald Knuth* said:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

You should see tables as a storage device for *entities*. For example if you are making an e-commerce website. It makes sense that there is a model for `Product`s, a model for `Order`, and a model in between (the junction table of a many-to-many relation between `Product` and `Order`) that determines how many times the product appears in the order.

By modeling this based on data, and not on a specific use case, it is usually simpler to add new features to your application. Furthermore it makes querying simpler, and therefore often has a positive effect on the overall performance.

Furthermore it is of importance to get used to the Django ORM tooling, and especially, as [@markwalker_ says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165586/comparative-database-metrics-for-different-implementations-of-django-model#comment120475043_68165586), with [**`select_related(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and  [**`prefetch_related(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method calls to load *in bulk* data that is related to the data you are retrieving. Often the *number* of queries to the database is already a strong indicator how efficient that program will run, not that much the exact queries: if your application makes a lot of queries, even simple ones, the number of roundtrips to the database will slow down the application significantly. If there is a bottleneck somewhere, then you can run a profiler and try to find parts of the code that needs to be optimized.

There is for example a package named [**`nplusone`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/jmcarp/nplusone) and [**`scout`**](https://scoutapm.com/blog/finding-and-fixing-n-1s-in-django-apps) can detect N+1 query problems that thus can be resolved with `select_related(…)` and `prefetch_related(…)`.